# Ecommerce pagination in Google SERP description

Tags: magento, seo, e-commerce

Any way to remove this other then messing up the syntax?

[image: Pagination in Google SERP]

HTML code:

```
<table class="toolbar" border="0">
<tr><td class="pager" style="width: 414px;">
<table class="pager" cellspacing="0">
<tr>
<td>Items 1 to 9 of 144 total</td>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Google does this automatically](http://insidesearch.blogspot.com.au/2011/08/new-snippets-for-list-pages.html). If you don't want it in your results you would need to reformat your page to not use a format that encourages them to do it. Otherwise it is out of your control.

Comment: So I need to mess up my HTML and english syntax :) thanks man